# Need to retrieve current vacancies from datatable

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

DateTime tday = Convert.ToDateTime(today);
return View(db.job.OrderBy(x => x.dateApplyBy >= tday).ToList());
```

I need to retrieve vacancies having date apply by greator than or equal to today.
but this query retrieving all vacancies.

Comment: You know that this is pointless: `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today)`? If you have already a `DateTime` you don't need to convert it to one. Where's the [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) at all?

Comment: `orderby` does sorting. You need `where` or `top` (limit) applied after sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't filtering your collection of jobs, simply ordering them.

```
return View(db.job.Where(j => j.dateApplyBy >= DateTime.Today).ToList());
```

Comment: @Muhammadfarhan:- You can accept the answer if that worked for you(*A right tick mark symbol turns green when clicked*)

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

DateTime tday = Convert.ToDateTime(today);
return View(db.job.Where(x = xdateApply >= today).OrderBy(x => x.dateApplyBy).ToList());
```